# Retrieving videos/photos from Vault app on Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Is it possible to retrieve photos/videos after uninstalling and reinstalling Vault app?  Please give me instructions how to retrieve.

Comment: They are no longer in gallery and I'm unable to locate on phone.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You will have to reinstall the app to use the files again. They're "encrypted" in a way such that only the Vault app can access them.